# What is the best and quick way to debug serialization exceptions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, serialization, session-state

Serialization exceptions are notorious and often dont have the complete stack trace to tell exactly which complex type is the culprit. I am trying to serialize a very complex type but facing exceptions like below.  Can any one tell me to quickly get culprit type. I tried putting [NonSerialized] on types which i suspect . But this is very laborious process..

**Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, none. It cannot be debugged as the code lives in an assembly that is dynamically generated.

However, checking stack trace and inner exceptions usually provides enough information to find the culprit.